# How do i execute this PowerShell command from cmd?

Tags: powershell, cmd

that is, the script should provide the license2.txt and then the powershell should filter the words **name | Key material** but I can't execute the command
powershell

```
(Get-content .\Licence2.txt) -replace "(</name|</keyMaterial )", "" >Licence.txt
```

Comment: Open a PowerShell Prompt, type `Get-Help Get-Content`, and read the output. PowerShell is clever enough to accept the shortest unique parameter string, as opposed to always using the full parameter. I would however advise that you do not use lazy code, or aliases until you are fully familiar with the language. You should for instance use `-Path`, or `-LiteralPath`, instead of just adding the filename without.

Comment: @Compo, the PowerShell command itself works. If I understand the question correctly, it is about calling the working PowerShell command _from `cmd.exe`_.

Comment: @mklement0, I never said it didn't. My response was after your posted comment, and a question about it by the OP. You posted your code, using `-c` instead of the more understandable `-Command` parameter. The OP asked what `-c` meant, so I directed them to the built-in help information, which they should have used before asking that question, and added a little explanation. Both of your comments have since been deleted, and you know it.

Comment: @Compo, of course I know my comments have been deleted, I always delete comments that have served their purpose. I didn't recognize your comment as being related to the question about `-c`, which is a _CLI_ parameter, because you were advising the OP to invoke help to learn about _`Get-Content`_'s parameters. Again, it seemed to me that you were discussing the specifics of the PowerShell command, which didn't need discussing.

Comment: P.S., @Compo. To get the _CLI_ help from inside a session, it is `help help about_powershell.exe` / `help about_pwsh`. I originally though that linking to the online version of `about_powershell.exe` would also explain the `-c` - which is an actual parameter _alias_, not an _abbreviation_ (well-known from other shells / scripting engines) - but it turns out that's only true for `about_pwsh` (PowerShell (Core) v6+): there, the official aliases are listed. The answer therefore now also mentions `-Command` explicitly.

Comment: Given that you didn't use `-Path` or `-LiteralPath`, I'm actually more surprised that you bothered with `-c` as an abbreviation for `-Command`, as `-Command` is the default if omitted, in just the same way.

Comment: @Compo, the aim was not to improve the OP's PowerShell command, but even if it was, I'm perfectly fine with using _positional_ arguments if it helps keep the command reasonably short, and I frequently do so in my own answers. By contrast, `-c` _is_ worth using explicitly, for consistency and disambiguation, because the default parameter _changed_ between `powershell.exe` and `pwsh`.

Comment: @mklement0, the comment section is a perfectly acceptable way, of providing advice to the poster on how to improve their submission, whereas the answer section is used to provide solutions. Also, from my perspective, I'd expect that any question involving separately installed versions of PowerShell, i.e. v6+, should use the appropriate tag to indicate that, and this one does not.

Comment: @Compo, no argument re the comments section. Personally, I was confused by your advice (I did not recognize it as relating to the OP's question about the meaning of `-c`, for the reasons stated), so my follow-up comment tried to counteract what I perceived to be a distraction from the issue at hand. There is no tagging issue here - I too assume that `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) is being targeted here. I merely provided a rationale for why I think using `-Command` (`-c`) and `-File` (`-f`) _explicitly_ is worthwhile in the grand scheme of things, going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order to execute a Windows PowerShell command from `cmd.exe` / a batch file, you need to call the former's CLI, `powershell.exe`, documented in [about_PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)** (for [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), it is `pwsh.exe` - see [about_Pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)).

The general approach to passing arbitrary PowerShell commands to `powershell.exe` from `cmd.exe` is:

- Enclose the command(s) in `"..."` *overall*, and pass that string to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter (which is `powershell.exe`'s  *implied* parameter, though note that `pwsh.exe` now defaults to `-File` (`-f`) instead, so it's better to be explicit).
- Escape any `"` characters that are *part of the command(s)* as `\"`<sup>[1]</sup>, or, if feasible, avoid embedded `"` quoting altogether and use embedded `'...'` quoting (*verbatim* PowerShell strings) that doesn't require escaping inside `"..."` at all.

Therefore, in your case:

```
powershell -c "(Get-Content .\Licence2.txt) -replace '</name|</keyMaterial ' > Licence.txt"
```

Note that I've omitted the unnecessary `(...)` from the regex passed to the `-replace` operator, as well as the unnecessary `""` replacement operand (replacing what matched with the empty string is the *default*).

Additionally, it is good practice to precede the `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`) parameter with `-NoProfile`, so as to suppress the unnecessary and potentially side-effect-inducing loading of the [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which are primarily intended for *interactive* sessions.

---

<sup>[1] If this fails (which happens if the characters between the `\"` delimiters contain `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` or `|`), use `"^""` with `powershell.exe`, and `""` with `pwsh.exe`.</sup>